# Download/Send file via AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to send a file via AWS Lambda but it's returning error(`TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")`).

I tried by encoding a zip file and send it along with the response. But it's returning error.

Here is my sample code:

```
import json
import base64
import zipfile

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    archive_name = '/tmp/test_file.zip'

    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, 'w') as zip_file:
        pass
    zip_file.close()

    image_processed = open(archive_name, 'rb')
    image_processed_data = image_processed.read()
    image_processed.close()
    res = base64.encodestring(image_processed_data)

    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': res,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        },
        'isBase64Encoded': True
    }
```

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "b'UEsDBBQAAAAAAEhAbU/8RgkRDgAAAA4AAAAJAAAAdG1wL2EudHh0S2FydGhpa2V5YW4gS1JQSwEC\\nFAMUAAAAAABIQG1P/EYJEQ4AAAAOAAAACQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtIEAAAAAdG1wL2EudHh0UEsFBgAA\\nAAABAAEANwAAADUAAAAAAA==\\n' is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
      238,
      "dumps",
      "**kw).encode(obj)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      199,
      "encode",
      "chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      257,
      "iterencode",
      "return _iterencode(o, 0)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
      134,
      "decimal_serializer",
      "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I attached the sample code which I tried and also added the error response from the Lambda.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `res` is `bytes`, so it's not Json serializable.

You could try:

```py
    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': res.decode(),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        },
        'isBase64Encoded': True
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually I want to save this bytes response to a file.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR Looks that returning `bytes` is unavaliable for pure Lambda. But you could follow these docs to integrate it with API Gateway. [Enable Binary Support Using the API Gateway Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html), [Binary Support for API Integrations with Amazon API Gateway](https://amazonaws-china.com/cn/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/)